Gauss-Jordan elimination for a $3\times 3$ matrix not matching given answer
I don't understand what I am doing wrong when attempting to get the inverse of this matrix using Gaussian Jordan Elimination.
$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
5 & -5 & 5\\
1 & 4 & -4\\
-1 & -2 & 3
\end{bmatrix}
$$
My answer is always just a little bit off of what the actual answer is, can anyone help? Thanks for taking the time.
Here is my work:

Here is the actual answer:


The problem is near the end in the step where you do
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3}\\
0 & 1 & -\frac{4}{3}\\
0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{matrix}
\left|
\,
\begin{matrix}
\frac{4}{15} & 1 & \frac{4}{3}\\
-\frac{1}{15} & 0 & -\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{2}{25} & \frac{3}{5} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right.
\right]
\overset{R_2 + R_1 \to R_2}{\longrightarrow}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3}\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\left|
\,
\begin{matrix}
\frac{4}{15} & 1 & \frac{4}{3}\\
\frac{3}{15} & 1 & 1\\
\frac{2}{25} & \frac{3}{5} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right.
\right]
$$
That operation should actually result in the matrix
$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
1 & 0 & \frac{4}{3}\\
1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{matrix}
\left|
\,
\begin{matrix}
\frac{4}{15} & 1 & \frac{4}{3}\\
\frac{3}{15} & 1 & 1\\
\frac{2}{25} & \frac{3}{5} & 1
\end{matrix}
\right.
\right]
$$
It would be better to instead do an operation that uses $R_3$ instead of $R_1$.
